# Flyway for databases containing billions of rows

Tags: database, migration, schema, large-data, flyway

I am looking for a schema manager (and probably not data) for my JAVA applications. I have multiple databases and tables with about 10+ billion rows.

How can I introduce Flyway into my applications? Is there a way to let Flyway only manage my schema (can be kept in a central repository), that is, generate migration scripts on detecting differences in the previous schema (something like RoR does) and just run `migrate` on other machines?

If not, is there a tool which could help me?